# Why there is the need of detaching and merging entities in a ORM?

Tags: orm, doctrine, doctrine-orm

The question is about Doctrine but I think that can be extended to many ORM's.

Detach:

> An entity is detached from an EntityManager and thus no longer managed
>   by invoking the `EntityManager#detach($entity)` method on it or by
>   cascading the detach operation to it. Changes made to the detached
>   entity, if any (including removal of the entity), will not be
>   synchronized to the database after the entity has been detached.

Merge:

> Merging entities refers to the merging of (usually detached) entities
>   into the context of an EntityManager so that they become managed
>   again. To merge the state of an entity into an EntityManager use the
>   `EntityManager#merge($entity)` method. The state of the passed entity
>   will be merged into a managed copy of this entity and this copy will
>   subsequently be returned.

I understand (almost) how this works, but the question is: why one would need detaching/merging entitiies? Can you give me an example/scenario when these two operations can be used/needed?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**When should I Detaching an entity?**
Detaching an entity from the an EM (EntityManager) is widely used when you deal with more than one EM and avoid concurrency conflicts, for example:

```
$user= $em->find('models\User', 1);
$user->setName('Foo');

// You can not remove this user, 
// because it still attached to the first Entity Manager
$em2->remove($user);
$em2->flush();
```

You can not take control of `$user` object by `$em2` because its session belongs to `$em` that initially load the `$user` from database. Them how to solve the problem above? You need to detaching the object from the original `$em` first:

```
$user= $em->find('models\User', 1);
$user->setName('Foo');

$em->detach($user);
$em2->remove($user);
$em2->flush();
```

**When should I use merging function?**
Basically when you want to  update an entity:

```
$user= $em->find('models\User', 1);
$user->setName('Foo');

$em->merge($user);
$em->flush();
```

The EM will make a compare between the $user in database vs the $user in memory. Once the EM recognize the changed fields, it only updates them and keeps the old ones.

<strike>The `flush` method triggers a commit and the user name will updated in the database</strike>

Comment: I agree with all said except with what is said about flush. The flush method synchronize the entities with the database but inside the transaction boundaries. This comes to play upon invoking a query within the very same transaction. Thus you quarantee that the processing of the query takes into account this very transaction updates.

Comment: This is a good explanation (+1), but why one should use more than one entity manager in the first place? Can't get it, sorry, using Doctrine always with one entity manager...

Comment: @Gremo, this could happen when you need are dealing with more than one datababase, so an EM per dabatase is required. At least this is one scenario

Answer (score 1):

You would need to detach an entity when dealing with issues of concurrency.

Suppose you are using an asynchronous API that makes callbacks to your project. When you issue the API call along with callback instruction, you might still be managing the entity that is affected by the callback, and therefore overwrite the changes made by the callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can also detach entity when you have pernamently data in your database, but in your code you modify this entities depending on the user account.

For example browser game which have some characters and some attacks to fight. **AttackOne** used by "UserFoo" (lvl 90) will be modified by better bonuses than used by "UserBarr" (lvl 20), but in our database **AttackOne** all the time is the same attack